# Am I looking at the right number for Earnings and EBITDA for Nokia?

Tags: corporate-earnings, price-earnings-ratio

I'm practicing how to read quarterly reports of publicly traded companies.  I'm looking at Nokia's with this link here:

https://www.nokia.com/system/files/2019-10/nokia_results_2019_q3.pdf

Am I correct in understanding the following:

- their earnings for Q3 is **85M Euros** as shown on page 25 **Profit/(loss) for the period = 85**
- their earnings for Q1 to Q3 is **-553M Euros** as shown on page 25 **Profit/(loss) for the period = (553)**
- their EBITDA for Q3 is **665M Euros** as shown on page 35 **EBITDA Non-IFRS**
- their EBITDA for Q1 to Q3 is **1406M Euros** as shown on page 35 **EBITDA Non-IFRS**

Did I read these numbers correctly?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Are you asking if those numbers are right or why they are different (e.g. why EBITDA is reported along with net earnings)?

Comment: I edited the question to just ask if I read those numbers correctly.  I'll write a separate question later on whether companies similar to NOKIA are expected to have substantial differences between Earnings and EBITDA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you read those correctly. The "Q1" values are earnings/EBITDA for the third quarter - the "Q1-Q3" values are the year-to-date totals, or the totals inclusive of Q1, Q2, and Q3.